# Can different id3v2 tags in the same song be of a different version (ex. version 2.3 and 2.4)?

Tags: mp3, music, id3, music-management

I'm confused on the difference between id3v2 version 2.3 and version 2.4 and would really appreciate it if anyone can clear this all up for me.

For example can the same file have **TIT2** tag of *Black Dog* and be of version 2.3 and a **TPE1** tag of *Led Zeppelin* be of version 2.4?

Also - How do you tell if a particular tag like **TIT2** is of version 2.3 or version 2.4?

And can you write the same tag ex **TIT2** in both 2.3 and 2.4 on a song to improve cross-device compatibility or must you choose only one version?